# vmc push of nodeJS report Application failed to start

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm learning CloudFoundry for the first time and during their hello-world nodeJS application I got "Application Failed to start." message.
The output is below. I try it with different name and got the same result.
If I try to browse this url I get 404 response.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.2

MyMac:hello-node ido$ vmc push
Name> ido-hello-node

Instances> 1

1: node
2: other
Framework> node

1: node
2: node06
3: node08
4: other
Runtime>

Runtime> node

1: 64M
2: 128M
3: 256M
4: 512M
5: 1G
Memory Limit> 64M

Creating ido-hello-node... OK

1: ido-hello-node.cloudfoundry.com
2: none
URL> ido-hello-node.cloudfoundry.com

Updating ido-hello-node... OK

Create services for application?> n

Save configuration?> n

Uploading ido-hello-node... OK
Starting ido-hello-node... OK
Checking ido-hello-node... **GAVE UP**

**Application failed to start.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sometimes find out what is wrong with your app by using the 'vmc logs' command, which will report what happened on the server.

Are you able to share the code?

Are you able to run your app locally successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell me what version of vmc, node are you using? Also did you npm install? Can you get the vmc logs?

Also use the updated tutorial here : http://cloudfoundry.github.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/javascript/

Thanks,

- Hitesh